# opengl object movements/switch statements

Tags: opengl, object, cube

anyone can teach me how to draw 2 objects, for example a cube and a sphere, in origin (0, 0, 0) and when i move the cube, the sphere just remains in the origin. same with moving the sphere, the cube remains..
using keyboardfunc.

```
if (!LightSwitch)
{ 
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(CubeX, CubeY, CubeZ);
glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glPushAttrib(GL_LIGHTING_BIT | GL_CURRENT_BIT);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, Green);
glutSolidCube(2.0);
glPopAttrib();
glPopMatrix();
glEnd(); 
}

if (!LightSwitch1)
{
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(AxisX, AxisY, AxisZ);
glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glPushAttrib(GL_LIGHTING_BIT | GL_CURRENT_BIT);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, Blue);
glutSolidSphere(2.0, 10.0, 5.0);
glPopAttrib();
glPopMatrix();
}
glEnd();
```

Comment: The glEnd() is unnecessary, but otherwise your drawing code seems ok.  The problem is probably somewhere else.  Have you printed the values of CubeXYZ and AxisXYZ to make sure they are what you expect?

Comment: the values of those are (0, 0, 0) which is the origin i guess..
but with my code, they both move at the same time

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but I believe that by having separate glPushMatrix() / glPopMatrix() blocks for the sphere and the cube, you are giving each object its own local coordinate system. This is why they transform independent of each other.

If you want to move them together, you need to specify glTranslate() outside your glPushMatrix() / glPopMatrix() first:

```
glTranslatef(translation....);     // Translates the whole scene 
glPushMatrix();
   glTranslatef(the sphere);       // Sphere & cube locations changeable via keyb.
   glTranslatef(the cube);
glPopMatrix();
```

If you want to, say, rotate the cube with respect to the sphere (ie., make the center of the sphere the origin of the cube's coordinate system), make a new glPushMatrix()/glPopMatrix() block nested within the first block:

```
glPushMatrix();
   glTranslatef(the sphere);       
        glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(the cube);       // Rotate about specific axis of the sphere
        glPopMatrix();
glPopMatrix();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code is correct for drawing the sphere at location Axis and the cube at location Cube. You say you are using a keyboard func and it is moving them both together when you want to move just one. I believe you are updating both sets of variables in your keyboard function. Try printing out CubeXYZ and AxisXYZ and make sure you're getting the right thing.